# PHP Looping number and row data from database

Tags: php

I want to create a line of numbers and different data
but, the result is :

B2, Data 1.1
B7, Data 1.1
B12, Data 1.1
...

B2, Data 2.1
B7, Data 2.1
B12, Data 2.1
...

I want the results like this :

B2, Data 1.1
B7, Data 2.1
B12, Data 3.1
...

B2, Data 1.2
B7, Data 2.2
B12, Data3.2
...

my code:

```
<?php
for ($i=2; $i < 100; $i++) {
  for ($j=2; $j < 100; $j++) {
    echo 'B' . $i+=5 . $row['column1'];
    echo 'B' . $i+=5 . $row['column2'];
    echo "<br>";
  }
}
?>
```

Thanks before :)

Comment: You have to post your sql query - how are column1 and column2 generated?

Comment: Also post your actual php code - the loop doesn't match your output

Comment: the sql query is just only standard mysql calling the data from the database, http://pastebin.com/NgaPQuDd

Comment: This is not creating the example output you have above: `echo 'B' . $i+=5 . $row['column1'];
    echo 'B' . $i+=5 . $row['column2'];`

Comment: ups, i'm very sorry, mistyping

Answer (score 0):

if your Table is like this:

```
id |column1 |column2
---------------------
1  |1       |1
2  |1       |2
3  |1       |3
4  |2       |1
5  |2       |2
6  |2       |3
7  |3       |1
8  |3       |2
9  |3       |3
```

And your SQL Query will be:

`SELECT * FROM`trial`ORDER BY column2, column1;`

the output of the query will be:

```
id |column1 |column2
---------------------
1  |1       |1
4  |2       |1
7  |3       |1
2  |1       |2
5  |2       |2
8  |3       |2
3  |1       |3
6  |2       |3
9  |3       |3
```

The data/rows of data you will retrieve/get will be based on how you will query the data.

So when you run your code:

```
<?php
for ($i=2; $i < 100; $i++) {
  for ($j=2; $j < 100; $j++) {
    echo 'B' . $i+=5 . $row['column1'];
    echo 'B' . $i+=5 . $row['column2'];
    echo "<br>";
  }
}
?>
```

it will produce your desired output:

```
B2, Data 1.1
B7, Data 1.1
B12, Data 1.1
... 
B2, Data 2.1
B7, Data 2.1
B12, Data 2.1
...
```